# Modo de criar página HTML com PHP

Tags: php, html, estilo-de-codificação

Não possuo muito conhecimento e não sei se o modo que estou fazendo está correto ou possui algum ponto negativo. Tem alguma opção melhor para que eu possa fazer?

```
<?php
$ht = '<div class="panel panel-headline">';
$ht .= '<div class="panel-heading">';
$ht .= '<form id="searchthis" method="get">';
$ht .= '<input id="namanyay-search-box" name="search" size="40" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>';
$ht .= '<button id="namanyay-search-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
$ht .= '</form>';
$ht .= '<h3 class="panel-title">Manage OneDrive Videos</h3>';
$ht .= '</div>';
$ht .= '<div class="panel-body" style="overflow: auto;">';
$ht .= '<table class="table table-hover">';

echo $ht;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

De forma geral não há problema em fazer assim, mas o pessoal costuma usar o sistema de *template*, ou seja, coloca-se em primeiro lugar o HTML e coloca um código PHP nas lacunas necessárias. O que não é o caso deste código, ou seja, esse exemplo deveria ser uma página estática HTML que nem passe pelo processador do PHP, seria absurdamente mais rápido assim.

Exemplo bem básico de como se costuma fazer:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo "1 + 1 é " . (1 + 1); ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GediSD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tyvpaykr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/HelloWorld.php).

Claro, o exemplo é bobo e assim também não precisaria passar pelo PHP, mas dá uma ideia de como é mais comum. O que você faria provavelmente é uma página que receberia o valor enviado pelo seu exemplo e trataria dando um resultado final que seria entregue para o navegador.